# Make jpa and coroutine repositories/r2dbc co live in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm working on kotlin/spring boot application and my main target is to make it reactive. For now this application use plain `JpaRepository` for data access and what I'm trying to do is to slowly rework repositories to use `CoroutineCrudRepository`, one by one. Surprisingly in spring it is not easy task to do:

- Simply extending `CoroutineCrudRepository` instead of `JpaRepository` lead to `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by JPA. Offending repository is MyReactiveRepository!`
- So in accordance with https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/ it seems that I need to add `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")` and `implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.13.RELEASE")` and make some changes to project to make it possible both jpa and coroutine repositories co-live in the same application.

Is there any guide talking about my concrete scenario? Any help is very appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Keep trying to make all this work:

- Added `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")` and `implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.13.RELEASE")` to make it possible to use `CoroutineCrudRepository`
- Added `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = ...)` and
  `@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = ...)` to divide different types of repositories.

All this led me to the following issue:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:  
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: ...

Error creating bean with name 'someJpaRepository' defined in obfuscated.package.SomeJpaRepository defined in 
  
@EnableJpaRepositories declared on MyApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6dbdbb69' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager';  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6dbdbb69': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument;  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Don't know how to resolve this for now cause it's not clear to me why jpa entityManagerFactory is not autoconfigured anymore.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2728 this is not supported